# Decision Tree Id3 algorithm implementation in Python from scratch

Tags: python, pandas, decision-tree

I just started learning machine learning .I am learning decision tress and I was trying to implement it in python from scratch. Actually,I used this site where the python code was  explained. (https://www.python-course.eu/Decision_Trees.php)

But I am not able to understand what the

```
        tree = {best_feature:{}}
```

part means. Is it a dictionary or  is it a part of the panda library? And also,it would be a great help if somebody explains this part

```
     parent_node_class = np.unique(data[target_attribute_name])[np.argmax(np.unique(data[target_attribute_name],return_counts=True)[1])]
```

What i Understood was this line of code finds the value from the target attribute that has the maximum frequency of occurence. Is this correct? If so,how could the target attriute become the parent node? Shouldn't it be the feature with the best information gain?

Also, please suggest some sites that have a simpler implementation of the algorithm.

Comment: `tree = {best_feature:{}}` is a dictionary which has the key `best_feature` and another dictionary as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer will be independent of the programming language you are using.

First, we have to have a set of data where each column name represents an attribute and in general the last column or attribute is the decision or result of that row.

The objective of the algorithm is to build a tree where the first nodes are the most useful questions (greater gain of information). But in order to decide which is the must calculate the entropy of each attribute.

So the first step is to know what the root attribute will be. To do this, he has to extract the entropy of each attribute and make the respective mathematical formulas so as to be able to obtain the information gain. This in order that in this iteration compare which of all has greater gain of information and therefore will be the root.

The following will be how each attribute has options, for example: Sky (Sunny, Rainy, Cloudy), then what it will do is calculate the information gain of each attribute option adding to the other attributes. To make it clearer, he looks in the data set for all the records that for example have: Sunny + all temperature, Sunny + all of Rainy. However, if the entropy of that option is 0, you will not need to ask any more questions.

And to the question you asked, the answer is that this attribute corresponds to the best feature. In other words, the feature with the highest information gain, therefore the one that benefits me the most, asking it first.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really helpful

Comment: I share the solution in javascript that you make of this algorithm. Unfortunately it's only in Spanish: [id3 js](https://github.com/Danils123/Id3Algoritmo.git)

Comment: That's ok ! Translate was helpful. Thanks a lot